# c# Program couldn't find config.ini file

Tags: c#, config, ini

Im using an older program to export some data to a csv. The program uses config.ini file to store some credentials. I've been using an c# console application for test purpose. The problem i have is that my program can't find any config.ini file.

[image]

I tried this block of code to receive the location of my project and the ini file but that doens't seem to work well.

```
 string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            Console.WriteLine(dir);
            string assname = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            Path.GetDirectoryName(assname);
            string filename = Path.Combine(dir, "config.ini");
            string ConfigFilePath = Path.Combine(dir, "config.ini");
```

This is my code for now:

```
static void CheckLogin()
        {
            string ConfigFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "config.ini");
            if (File.Exists(ConfigFilePath))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Options and Credentials are imported from config.ini ...");

                StreamReader IniFile = new StreamReader(ConfigFilePath);

                while (!IniFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    String Line = IniFile.ReadLine();
                    string[] LineValues = Line.Split(':');
                    string Value = string.Join(":", LineValues, 1, LineValues.Length - 1);

                    switch (LineValues[0])
                    {
                        case "DevId":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.Talk2MDevId = Value;
                            break;
                        case "APIToken":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.APIToken = Value;
                            Console.WriteLine(Value);
                            break;
                        case "DeleteData":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.DeleteData = Value.ToLower().StartsWith("y");
                            break;
                        case "CSVFilename":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.CSVFilename = Value;
                            break;
                        case "CSVTitle":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.CSVTitle = Value;
                            break;
                        case "CSVLineFormat":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.CSVLineFormat = Value;
                            break;
                        case "DateTimeFormat":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.DateTimeFormat = Value;
                            break;
                        case "CSVOutputDir":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.CSVOutputDir = Value;
                            break;
                        case "ForceRetrieveAll":
                            Properties.Settings.Default.TransactionId = "0";
                            break;
                    }             
                                               
                }

                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                IniFile.Close();
                //Delete the config file not to store the credentials in a all users accessible directory
                File.Delete(ConfigFilePath);
            }
```

i've never worked with .ini files so if some can help me out here how to locate the .ini file? it will be very helpfull!

Comment: You need to clarify if the `ini` is actually not found first. For example, does `StreamReader` read anything? When you output `ConfigFilePath` during running, is it correct path?

Comment: The path is correct but it immediately throws this error : "No config.ini file detected, please create a config.ini"

Comment: Is this .NET Core or .NET Framework? The configuration middleware in .NET Core (which includes .NET5/6) handles INI files already, among others. Also, why are you using `Properties.Settings.Default` like this? Even in .NET Old, that's now how config properties are retrieved. `Properties.Settings` is only used for a very specific config section. BTW these quirks are why .NET Core discarded the old `app.config` and `Properties.Settings`

Comment: The error might have been from other places in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can list your files in application working directory like this :

```
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var files =Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);
```

and you can find your config file with this :

```
var conf = files.FirstOrDefault(name => name.EndsWith(".ini"));
```

or

```
var conf = files.FirstOrDefault(name => name == "config.ini");
```